# How to start an activity with custom animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I wrote code that starts an activity with animation from a given static point (pivotX, pivotY) but I want to change pivotX and pivotY before the activity starts. I want the animation to start when I click a point on my map.

**XML:**

```
<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fillBefore="false"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="10%p"
    android:pivotY="50%p"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

**Activtity:**

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PlayerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in,
                    R.anim.push_down_out);
```

Comment: hey did you get answer for this question

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is some problem with your animation file. Follow these steps.

put activity_push_up_in.xml in your anim folder :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />

</set>
```

now, put another xml push_up_out.xml again in your anim folder :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="-100%p" />

</set>
```

Now put this code in your java file to start activity with this animation :-

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
```

Comment: i asked other question.

Comment: may be I didn't get you can you explain it.

Comment: so that my animation start one point of screen and after 1 second the activity is full screen. I ask that how can i start animation from given point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use android:startOffset to set the animation delay